# Открытие всех директорий проекта в QtCreator

Tags: c++, qtcreator

Пишу на C++, в качестве IDE использую CLion, однако, он слишком громоздкий для домашнего использования на старом ноуте, и я в данный момент пробую QtCreator.

Подскажите, можно ли в QtCreator (4.12) открыть папку проекта целиком (со всякими doc, конфигами и прочим), так же, как в CLion? Пока что открывается только хедеры и сорцы, в настройках подобной опции не нашел.

Comment: Это кажется окошко file system/

Comment: Да, есть окно файловой системы. А через окно проектов, насколько понимаю, можно увидеть только то, что явно включено в проект через *.pro файлы

Comment: Да, увидел, спасибо. Получилось открыть через filesystem, хоть и показалось не очень удобным. Благодарю.